# DRF nested-relationships : related_name argument

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In DRF documentation:

> You'll normally want to ensure that you've set an appropriate
>   related_name argument on the relationship, that you can use as the
>   field name.
>
> If you have not set a related name for the reverse relationship,
>   you'll need to use the automatically generated related name in the
>   fields argument.

My Room model has the following :

```
hotel = models.ForeignKey(
    Hotel,
    related_name="%(class)s_rooms",
    verbose_name=u'Hotel')
```

How to add this to the Hotel serializer?
I tried `fields = ('room_set', ...)` but I get

> ImproperlyConfigured at /api/hotel/ Field name `room_set` is not
>   valid for model `Hotel`.

Comment: What if you add `fields = ('hotel_rooms',)`?

Comment: get the same error

Comment: Do you use `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` or just `ModelSerializer`?

Comment: It's just ModelSerializer

Comment: @Hisham What is your model class name?

Comment: Why do you use `%(class)s`? If your class is named `Room` it will resolve to `room_rooms`, and that doesn't make a lot of sense. Is it an abstract class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The related name for `Hotel` in your model class `Room` resolves as `hotel_rooms`. If you want to include the relationsship in your serializer class, you can try something like this:

```
class HotelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # as of the updates based on your comments this may become obsolete
    hotel_rooms = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Hotel
        fields = ('hotel_rooms',) # put all other fields you need
        # add depth for displaying nested contents
        depth = 1
```

UPDATE:

There is an error in my first sentence. The `related_name` will not resolve to `hotel_rooms`, but to `room_rooms`, assuming the class name is `Room`. The `related_name` should be meaningful and in this case `hotel_rooms` or even just `rooms` makes perfectly sense. When you have the hotel, you can query the hotel rooms:

```
hotel = Hotel.objects.get(pk=1)
hotel.hotel_rooms.all() # or hotel.rooms.all()
```

You didn't reveal the need for the use of `%(class)s_rooms`. It makes sense to use it in abstract classes that will be inherited from other model classes or when using the `ContentType` framework, where the actuall class name is not yet known at the time of the declaration of `related_name`.

Comment: I tried this option before and get: 'Hotel' object has no attribute 'hotel_rooms'

Comment: room_rooms works fine.. thanks, but it just display IDs : [{"id":1,"nombreht":"Damarose","room_rooms":[1,2,3,7,8,9,10,11,76,77]}] , how to display all objects of Room?

Comment: @Hisham Yes, `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` displays only the primary keys as a list. You have to add the attribute `depth` and set the value to 1 (I think that should work for this case). If you want to traverse deeper trough your relations you have to set other value.

Comment: @Hisham Did you try to remove `room_rooms` (`hotel_rooms` in the code example above) `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`?

Comment: Perfect, how I did't try it :))

Answer (score 1):

Use **`fields = ('modelname_rooms', ...)`**

Assuming you have a model class as,

```
class Hotel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=123)


class MyModel(models.Model):
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, related_name="%(class)s_rooms", verbose_name=u'Hotel')
```

and in your `HotelSerializer`,

```
class HotelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Hotel
        fields = ("mymodel_rooms",)
```

That is you have to add a **prefix** to **`_room`** to use the `related_field`. Here the `prefix` is the **name of the model class in `lower case` letters**.

Answer (score 0):

Too large for comment. But could you check the *related_name* seems like there is issue with the format, unless you put it intentionally.

```
hotel = models.ForeignKey(
    Hotel,
    related_name="abcs_rooms", # update this line
    verbose_name=u'Hotel')
```